# Calcular o Horário em C. Exercício

Tags: c, data, scanf, helper

Comecei programar recentemente e estou com problemas em resolver esse exercício:

> Escreva um programa que leia o horário (horas e minutos) de partida de um voo, o tempo de viagem e a diferença em horas do fuso horário do destino. O programa deve informar qual será o horário local no destino previsto para a chegada do voo. Lembrando que o voo pode chegar no dia seguinte.

estou com problema na parte de fazer a scanf da data e hora e também o fuso.

Comment: E como você vai representar as horas, os minutos e o fuso horário (ou será a diferença de horas)?

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/112052

Comment: Qualquer forma forma pode ser . o fuso de somar ou subtrair.

Comment: hkotsubo, estou pedindo para me ajuda não fazer para mim, estou nesse exercicio a 2 dias sem conseguir resolver e vi muitos tutoriais e pesquisei. Se não quer ensinar, abraço e tenha um bom dia..

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Sobre o que o colega @hkotsubo comentou, é a ajuda útil nesse momento, tem essa outra aqui também: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70). Se não quer aprender os requisitos para perguntas feitas no site, bom... abraço e tenha um bom dia. Se quiser, por outro lado, tem muito material legal à disposição, só ficar atento às orientações dos colegas mais experientes.

Comment: @Bacco você confundiu as intenções do hkotsubo abra o link e vera que é direcionado ao post "Achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça", não ouve nenhuma tentativa de ajuda. Comecei a programar agora e não sei as regras do site ou a cultura dos programadores, irei ler os links que me mandou para me informar mais. Obrigado.

Comment: @EduardoFabricio o link é documento oficial da comunidade, e tem muito mais informação do que essa que te incomodou (se sugeriram, cabe a você fazer com que o post não se encaixe nos problemas listados). Se ler com intenção de aprender vai ter coisa útil lá (e no outro link que passei). Essas orientações servem para você entender o que funciona e o que não dá certo aqui, e principalmente como cumprir com os objetivos do site (se entende, todos ganham, se não entende acaba saindo insatisfeito e ainda deixa postagens que atrapalham a comunidade). Não é uma disputa.

Comment: Quando vc só coloca o enunciado e não põe o código que já tentou, nem explica de forma objetiva o problema ("estou com problema para fazer X" é uma descrição bem vaga), **a impressão que passa** é que só quer que façam tudo pra vc, daí o link que informei. Se ler os demais links também entenderá que a ideia do site não é fornecer helpdesk individual. E só pra constar, a resposta abaixo pode resultar em horários negativos dependendo do fuso horário, então ela nem deveria ser aceita, isso acaba fazendo com que a qualidade do site - que já não anda boa - caia ainda mais em descrédito...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando campos inteiros defina e leia hora da partida (0 a 23), minuto da partida (0 a 59), horas de duração do voo (0 a 24), minutos de duração do voo (0 a 59), diferença em horas do fuso horário do destino (-12 a +12).
Calcule:

```
minuto de chegada = minuto da partida + minutos de duração do voo
se (minutos de chegada > 60) então
    hora extra = 1
    minuto de chegada = minuto de chegada - 60
senao
    hora extra = 0
    fimse
hora de chegada = hora da partida + horas de duração do voo + hora extra - fuso horário do destino
se (hora de chegada > 24) então
    dia = 1
    hora de chegada = hora de chegada - 24
senao
    dia = 0
fimse
imprima dia, hora e minuto de chegada
```

Outra possibilidade é utilizar os tipos de dados e funções de `<time.h>`.

Comment: consegui resolver fazendo umas gambiarras doidas que nem sei por que ta funcionando, mas valeu.